# hook in jquery for toggle

Tags: jquery, hook

I created a page contains the following code. There I need to alert a message. But it does not work. WHY ?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.hook('toggle');
    $('#test').bind('onbeforetoggle', function(e){alert(e.type)});

    $('#btnHide').click(function() {
        $('#divTest').toggle();

    });

});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mraufk/dUhWe/)

Comment: Why do you think it should work? jQuery has no `hook` method. And btw. you did not select jQuery as library for your jsFiddle. *Edit*: Ah, you added it as external resource.... it's easier to select it from the "Choose Framework" list.

Comment: Hook must be a 3d party plugin. could you give us more info and your jsfiddle demo is trying to use mootools.

Comment: I think he's referring to this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryHook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope some helps

http://jsfiddle.net/TzCXC/

```
  (function($){
    $.hook = function (fns) {
        fns = typeof fns === 'string' ? 
            fns.split(' ') : 
            $.makeArray(fns)
        ;

        jQuery.each( fns, function (i, method) {
            var old = $.fn[ method ];

            if ( old && !old.__hookold ) {

                $.fn[ method ] = function () {
                    this.triggerHandler('onbefore'+method);
                    this.triggerHandler('on'+method);
                    var ret = old.apply(this, arguments);
                    this.triggerHandler('onafter'+method);
                    return ret;
                };

                $.fn[ method ].__hookold = old;

            }
        }); 

    };

    $.unhook = function (fns) {
        fns = typeof fns === 'string' ? 
            fns.split(' ') : 
            $.makeArray(fns)
        ;

        jQuery.each( $.makeArray(fns), function (i, method) {
            var cur = $.fn[ method ];

            if ( cur && cur.__hookold ) {               
                $.fn[ method ] = cur.__hookold;         
            }
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Its Ok, Why should I write this much code ? Please look at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryHook

Comment: @mraufk - Actually,your link use 3d party plugin too. see the link [Try out a demonstration](http://github.com/aheckmann/jquery.hook/raw/master/test.html) in [http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryHook](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryHook), you can find a script `<script src="jquery.hook.js">` in the page source `<head>`.